# C - Scanf with only read/write

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to write my own scanf function in C using only read/write (no libary functions, no va_args etc.). I came up with this code (only for decimal integers for now):

```
void myscanf(char* text, ... ) {
  char* ap = (char *) &text + sizeof text;
  char* p;
  int tempk;

  for(p=text; *p != '\0'; p++){
    if(*p=='%'){
        p++;
        switch (*p) {
            case 'd':
                char data[128] = { 0 };
                read(0, data, 128);
                tempk = StringToInt(data, 10);
                int* k = (int*)ap;
                *k = tempk;
                break;
        }
    }
  }
```

}

For some reason the address of *k is different from pointer I pass as an argument. I tried different ways, but I sill don't know how to get the right address.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with int* k = (int*)ap and line after this *k=tempk, one of these has no reason to be there

Comment: Assuming you already was told, that what you are doing is very dirty, sick, implementation dependent etc... What exact system/compiller are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04/gcc

Comment: That was not my idea, It's homework

Comment: For actually to do `scanf` you *need* to implement buffering of at least one character. Minimally you will read the stream character by character, then implement the `ungetc` function. Your immediate problem, however, is that you need to learn how to use the variable arguments (varargs). They do not work at all like you expect them to be here.

Comment: In main I have variable int k; then I call myscanf("%d", &k); but the address myscanf gets is different from the actual k's address. The difference is very small. c0 or c8 (hex)

Comment: @iamjustasking that's your problem. You get a value that "almost makes sense". If you got total garbage, you'd not think you're right at all (your approach is very wrong).

Comment: Instead follow the advice of the duplicate, and to get the `int *`, use `int * ptr = va_arg(list, int *);`

Comment: I'm not allowed to use stdarg.h library

Comment: @iamjustasking what! there is no way of doing this portably in C then. (i.e. it wouldn't work in any 64-bit computer one could find) Whose course is this?!

Comment: Operating systems

Comment: it doesn't have to be done portably and i'm compiling it for 32-bit machine

Comment: @iamjustasking You have already use va_arg with your function, "`...`" already use `va_arg`, tell this to your school for me.

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution should be int* k = (int **)ap; and -fno-stack-protector when compiling